# system settings not showing any thing

Tags: networking, software-center, settings

I updated my ubuntu 18.04, after updating,system settings not showing any thing, i tried sollutions like apt-get install unity-control-center but no one works for me coz it needs to have connection but in my case also network not working and lot of cammandes of network are not installed like ifconfig gives to me: (the commande ifconfig not found but can be installed using  : sudo apt install net-tools). i also tried to install unity-control-center manually but i don't found the package to install. Please i need your help

Comment: 18.04 uses gnome desktop now, unless you have upgraded from earlier version or installed unity desktop, unity tools won't work.

Comment: Is wired and wireless not working on that computer?  Let us know how/what with you are connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some important packages were not automatically installed or they have been removed.

So your first option will be to try:

`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`

If this doesn't help then you must try to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`. This is a sure shot way of getting all the missing packages.

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Depending upon whats missing it might take a while and you would need an internet connection for this to work.